# How do I create a sandbox for each customer in PHP?

Tags: php, security, plugins, sandbox, add-on

I have a problem, I stay right now and will create powerful software for multipule users. I want to make it possible for a customer to create their own plugins/addons for this system, but i don't like the customer can read all my "defineds" and "global vars" and more...

Now I search after a solution for this. My idea is to build a sandbox for each customer where I can define what happens in this sandbox and it will not be possible for the customer to have contact with my system code.

Can somebody maybe help me by linking to sites where I can find more information about how to make such a system?

Answer (score 0):

You need to investigate Plugin Architecture.

There is an introduction to this concept here:

http://shameerc.com/2010/12/simple-plugin-architecture-using-php5-reflection-api.html